# Loop has gone crazy

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This loop keeps giving me my error message even when I enter a valid input and I can't find what is wrong with it. It's the same as my other loops in the program which all work fine. Does anyone know the problem? Here is the loop:

```
System.out.println("Male or Female (M/F)");
    gender = userInput.next().charAt(0);
    gender = Character.toLowerCase(gender);

    while((gender != 'm') || (gender != 'f')) {
        System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a valid age");
        System.out.println("Male or Female (M/F)");
        gender = userInput.next().charAt(0);
        gender = Character.toLowerCase(gender);
    }//end while
```

Now if I type 'm' or 'f' it will give me the error message? ??? ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while((gender != 'm') || (gender != 'f')) {
```

should really be

```
while((gender != 'm') && (gender != 'f')) {
```

The condition `(gender != 'm') || (gender != 'f')` always evaluates to `true`. To understand why, consider one case - `gender = 'm'`...

```
(gender != 'm') || (gender != 'f')
('m'    != 'm') || ('m'    != 'f')
false           || true
true
```

Basically, java doesn't know the common English idiom `if gender isn't (either) male or female`.

Comment: Ah no need to feel that way, many mistakes come down to a small logical error or an errant bracket! Mark his answer as accepted if it resolved your issue though! Good karma goes a long way!